# Launch Google Form via Appscript as a Custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to launch a Google Form that I created from a Google Sheet, via App Script. The script does not work and I am not sure what needs to be done to fix it. Here is the script:

---

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Edit/Delete', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('New Entry', 'menuItem2')
      .addToUi();
    }

function menuItem1() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi () // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
    }

function menuItem2() {
// Open a fom.     var form =  FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfYrw3nwiYt6p8bPEqyV0GD8hpnaFOfa1i4LHYMo01GPPM6dQ/viewform');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this task. My Code.gs would like like this. It opens a mini modal. Let me know what you think.

```
 function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Edit/Delete', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('New Entry', 'menuItem2')
      .addToUi();
    }

function menuItem1() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi () // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
    }

function menuItem2() {

 // Here register an HTML template that will render a modal/popup.
 // 'form' is the name of a new 'form.html' file
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(50)


 // Here call the modal/pop to open when the menu button 'MenuItem2' is 
 // clicked

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Form');
}
```

I would then have another html file call "form.html" which will render a modal when it is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Open Form

    <!-- Below is an HTML trick to open a url in a new tab automatically -->
    <!-- change the action url to any that is needed  -->
    <!-- foo can be any string -->
    <form action='http://example.com' method='get' id='foo'></form>
    <script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The file structure in the Appscript should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am new to this technology but I do have  a software development back ground.  I have some questions-  1. What do you mean when you say the code.gs  opens a mini modal?   2.   I create the file form.html  is this what is  referenced in the HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile?  3.  What needs to be in place or substituted for the example.com and the id='foo'.   
Thank you.
Jack M. Stein
704-792-0615 (home)
412-848-6534 (Cell)

Comment: I updated the code a little with comments. Here are the answers to your questions. 

1) The Code.gs registers that there is an HTML template. When clicking the menu button the HTML template will render a modal on the page, when the modal comes up a new browser tab will open with the stated url. 

2) Yes. The ".html" will be added automatically. 

3) example.com would be the link to your google form. 'foo' is just an element id it can stay like that or be any string you choose.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to run the script.   
No HTML file named form was found.  Details   Dismiss     I have also included the google form  in place of example.com       
    <form action='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfYrw3nwiYt6p8bPEqyV0GD8hpnaFOfa1i4LHYMo01GPPM6dQ/viewform' method='get' id='foo'></form>
    <script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>    
  </body>
</html>

Comment: I updated with some screen shots of the app-script. The warning suggests you might not have the form.html file quite right.

Comment: Well, I added the foo.html as a separate file in my Google Drive and that was not appropriate.   Based on what I see in your screen shot I created the html file in the Google script editor and it now I am not getting the warning.   What I am getting is  a dialog with the word Form    Open Form.  All I can do is dismiss it and then nothing happens.   Is the URL for the syntax  for the form correct:                          <form action='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfYrw3nwiYt6p8bPEqyV0GD8hpnaFOfa1i4LHYMo01GPPM6dQ/viewform' method='get' id='foo'></form>

Comment: Not sure if this will work but here is a working example with the script. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aHSRx2Inid8Oj8ijvD1duN7G5uSLSh91hXgkpxzTi8A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I get the following error running the script from the link you gave -     Authorization Required
A script attached to this document needs your permission to run.